# Convert script from Mootools to Jquery

Tags: jquery, input, mootools, hidden, checkbox

I have this script written in Mootools.

When any checbox is checked, then hidden input is changed. Script check every checked image, makes string from checkced images - separated by commas. I need this Mootools script convert to jQuery.

[jsFiddle Mootools script](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/pfJYh/8/)

HTML :

```
<form>
    <div class="img_container">
        <img src="http://ynternet.sk/test/bg_1.png" style="border:2px solid gray;" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="bg_1.jpg" checked="yes"  />
    </div>
    <div class="img_container">
        <img src="http://ynternet.sk/test/bg_2.png" style="border:2px solid gray;" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="bg_2.jpg" checked="yes"  />
    </div>
    <div class="img_container">
        <img src="http://ynternet.sk/test/bg_3.png" style="border:2px solid gray;" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="bg_3.jpg" checked="yes" />
    </div>

<input type="hidden" value="bg_1.jpg,bg_1.jpg,bg_3.jpg" name="selected_img">
```

Mootools

```
var checks = document.getElements('input[type="checkbox"]');
var hidden = document.getElements('input[type="hidden"][name="selected_img"]')[0];
checks.addEvent('change',function(e){
    var checkbox = e.target;
    var img = checkbox.getPrevious('img');
    var checked = checkbox.get('checked');
    if(checked){
      img.setStyle('border','2px solid gray');
    }
    else{
      img.setStyle('border',null);
    }

    setInputHidden();
});

function setInputHidden(){
    var inputs_checked = document.getElements('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');  
    var arr_names = inputs_checked.get('name');
    hidden.set('value',arr_names.join(','));
    alert(hidden.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().find('img').css({
            'borderLeft': '2px solid gray',
            'borderRight': '2px solid gray',
            'borderTop': '2px solid gray',
            'borderBottom': '2px solid gray',
        });
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('img').css({
            'borderLeft': '0',
            'borderRight': '0',
            'borderTop': '0',
            'borderBottom': '0',
        });
    }

    setInputHidden();
});

function setInputHidden() {
    var arr_names = new Array();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        arr_names.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    $('input[type=hidden][name=selected_img]').val(arr_names.join(','));
    alert($('input[type=hidden][name=selected_img]').val());
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it does not work :( 
http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/pfJYh/12/

Comment: made a couple of small edits. this now does everything with the inputs, but in jsfiddle, for some reason doesnt toggle the image border. ill make a fix for this in a moment

Comment: thank you, it woks great :) I have one question... When I press JSHint button on jsFiddle, it says, that in this line is some error "var arr_names = new Array();"... just for my curiosity, why is this marked as error ? :)

Comment: Array is uppercase, should be lowercase to make sure it is absolutely valid across all browsers.

Comment: I made a few more edits, removing inline style in place of css classes, using `.on('change', function() {})`, swapping the alert with console.log, and new Array() with `[]` : http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/kmMmy/

Comment: just one question... May I use name for hidden input something like array name ? for example "selected_img[]" ? Is it possible in jQuery ?